# VBA dynamic checkboxes positioning

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, userform

I have an Excel VBA userform where I am attempting to add a number of checkboxes according to the number of items in a given dictionary.

This works, but each of my checkboxes is added to the top left corner, on top of each other. How can I place them so that the newest one is immediately below the previous?

Here is my relevant code:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Variable Checkboxes
Dim i As Long
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
For i = 1 To .count - 1
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = .Keys()(i)
    chkBox.VALUE = False  
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one issue is how you are assigning Checkbox.  Try using Checkbox instead of MSForms.Checkbox.  More options may appear, including the Top option:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Variable Checkboxes
Dim i As Long
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
For i = 1 To .Count - 1
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = .Keys()(i)
    chkBox.Value = False
    chkBox.Top = ...enter top location here...

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I had seen references to Top and Left, and was confused why I didn't have them. I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Actually, using this code I'm getting a type mismatch on the Set chkbox line. I assume this is because I'm adding a Forms.Checkbox.1. Is there an alternative ProgID for another type?

Comment: Checkbox is a member of MSForms.  But is giving different options depending on how it is called.  Frustrating thing about VBA as it happens sometimes.  if you use Dim chkBox As MSFOrms.Checkbox, it appears to accept the .Top method, even though it doesn't show up in the context scroll down.  You also may need to include chkBox.Visible = True to have it show on the form.  Let me know if that solves it.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the position relative to the their container by using the `Left` and `Top` properties.

So in this case, to stack them on top of each other, you can do something like this:

```
Const Spacing As Integer = 8 ' Gap between controls.
For i = 1 To .count - 1
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
    ' Position the new checkbox.
    ' This assumes all will be the same size.  
    chkBox.Top = (chkBox.Height + Spacing) * (i - 1)
    ...  
Next
```

You will likely want to play with this a bit, but this should hopefully get you started.